# Conditional Sum IF Using Indirect

Tags: excel

I have a years worth of spread sheets labeled by month. I would like to SUM specific positions's FTE counts based on position type and selected month.

So for example, column A = Position; Column P = FTE. I want to create a drop down list (which I have already done) so when you select specific month the FTE amount will be summed by position type.

I have the SUMIF formula for a single spreadsheet but am having trouble incorporating the INDIRECT function into this formula. So the code below states if row A = CLINICAL ASSOCIATE I want to sum the FTE values in row P.

```
=SUMIF('June 2019'!A:A,"CLINICAL ASSOCIATE", 'June 2019'!P:P)
=SUMIF('June 2019'!A:A,"ATTENDING", 'June 2019'!P:P)
=SUMIF('June 2019'!A:A,"FELLOW", 'June 2019'!P:P)
```

I know it needs to be along the lines of:

Cell B3 is the cell that contains the drop down list of months.

```
=SUMIF(Indirect(B3&"!....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'" & B3 & "'!A:A"),"CLINICAL ASSOCIATE", INDIRECT("'" & B3 & "'!P:P"))
```